# Low Graphics Crash in MATLAB 2016b

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

MATLAB show Low Graphics Error when it strats. Everytime I  Execute my MATLAB 2016b, It runs properly, but after some time I got Crash message as shown in Fig. I have already update my Graphics Driver, My Laptop is equipped with I7 Processor, 8 GB RAM, 2 GB Graphic Card. 
I already use command opengl('save','software') but no solution is there. 
Please help me.

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Comment: Might be something wrong with the MATLAB configurations. You can try deleting the contents of the output of `prefdir`, reinstalling MATLAB, or running in gui-less mode.

Comment: You should probably contact MATLAB technical support. Do you have a campus license? If so they usually want you to contact them through campus IT, or whomever is the license contact.